# How To Go To Website Link In specific Slideradapter ViewPager 2 Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How To Go To Website Link In specific Slideradapter ViewPager 2 Android Studio?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder viewHolder, int position) {
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(position==0){
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Ini Adalah Foto Pertama", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if (position==1){
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Ini Adalah Foto Kedua", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else  if (position==2){
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Ini Adalah Foto Ketiga", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you facing is really simple to solve. You just have to follow my steps down below.

Step -1

copy this codes

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
        Uri.parse("http://www.particular-website.com/"));
      startActivity(viewIntent);
```

and replace is it with your 'Toast'.
Thank you. I hope this might solve your problem. Please do share your thoughts on this.

Happy Coding